# Can I create a container image with docker-compose build?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I've got an app that currently has several containers - and I'd like to just build the web container, isolated, to send to AWS ECS. The docker-compose.yml currently contains info for web's ports, command, env, etc, and the actual dockerfile for my web container just has the python version.

If I use `docker build .` from the app/web directory, I don't think the port settings from the docker-compose file come through. Is it possible to use docker-compose build web? Or do I need to fill out the dockerfile in my web directory? I want to push only my web container image to ECS

As for why I'm doing this, I think that locally I'll develop with redis, nginx, and postgres - but ECS has their own options, so I won't need to use these containers.

Is there some major misunderstanding here that someone could clear up?

Comment: docker-compose build web should word. Have you already tried?

Answer (score 1):

The only way the port settings can be stored in your docker image is by use of the `EXPOSE` command in your Dockerfile. This tells docker that those ports will have something listening on them at runtime. Docker uses this information if you provide the `-P` option to `docker run`, when it will bind all ports which are `EXPOSE`d in the image to random high-numbered ports on the host. It also uses this information to make these ports available to any linked containers, even if they are not published to the host.

In short everything will work 100% fine creating and pushing an image without using `EXPOSE` in your Dockerfile (because you are already mapping the ports in your docker-compose.yml) but if you are sharing the resulting image with others then it would be good practice to `EXPOSE` all the ports your app listens on in the Dockerfile.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ecs-cli` to push a docker-compose file to ecs. The workflow is sort of like this:

1) run `ecs-cli configure` and tell it what cluster to use

2) Build the docker image

3) Tag it with a version based on git commit or date or both

4) Push the docker image to the ecs repository

5) run `ecs-cli compose service up`

This is sort of the script I am using

```
rm ~/.ecs/config
ecs-cli configure --region eu-central-1 --access-key AYAYAYAYAYAY1212121 --secret-key secretfaskdjfalsdfkja;sdjfalsdf --cluster "<clustername>"  


VERSION="$(git log --pretty=format:'%h' -n 1)-$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S)"
docker tag image_name:latest "123123123123.abc.def.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/image_name:$VERSION"  
docker push "123123123123.abc.def.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/image_name:$VERSION" 

VERSION="$VERSION" ecs-cli compose --file <path/to/docker-compose.yml> -p <service-name> service up
```

docker-compose.ymp sample:

```
version: '2'
services:
  stage-backend:
    image: 123123123123.abc.def.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/image_name:${VERSION}
    cpu_shares: 750
    mem_limit: 1000000000
    ports:
      - "0:8080"
    environment:
      FOO: "bar"
```

This creates a new instance of a task and then configures your service to run that task.